# Recommend on classic tutorials with Bayesian Time Series Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bayesian, references

I am currently planning to do something with Bayesian machine learning for time series data analysis. Does anyone know any classic books or tutorials that give complete instructions on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Introduction to Time Series Analysis and Forecasting" (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics) 2nd Edition by Montgomery,‎ Jennings,‎ and Kulahci has a nice (but very brief) introduction to the topic in Chapter 7.

There is also "Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models" by West and Harrison (I personally haven't read it).

Many texts and tutorials treat Bayesian forecasting under the more general category of State Space time series models. You might want to look those up.